# How to put jQuery Dialog popup div into the jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple message to display in one jQuery popup and I just want to generate it without adding extra divs into my HTML.

What I'd like to do is just open a dialog box with a message and thats it.

Here is something like that I want:

```
$("<div>Hello sir</div>").dialog("open");
```

But that doesn't work.  Should it? It seems like that should just open a simple dialog box, shouldn't it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `open`, simply:

```
$('<div />').html('Hello sir').dialog();
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aVSbc/2/).

Comment: Thank you that worked.  Will accept this answer in 6 min when StackOverflow lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure you have included jQuery.UI library in addition to core jQuery ?

see example here :
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: Yes and I am able to open the dialog boxes in other places where I reference a div in the html code.

Answer (score 1):

`$("<div>This is a test</div>").dialog();`

works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/fyMct/